# Is there an integer-arithmetic algorithm to compute the continued fraction expansion of the square root of a rational number?

Tags: continued-fractions

There is a well known algorithm (Bhaskara-Brouncker) to compute the continued fraction expansion of the square root of an integer, using integer arithmetic only, no floating point.

Is such an algorithm known also for square roots of fractions of integers?

Comment: see  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/indefinite_binary_Buell.pdf